# Pushing x:latest which is the same image as x:<semver-version>

Tags: docker, docker-push, docker-tag

I ran this:

```
docker build -t "oresoftware/live-mutex-broker:1.0.2" .
docker push "oresoftware/live-mutex-broker:1.0.2"
```

that worked. So how can I can then tag this as latest, and "push" the same image to

```
docker push "oresoftware/live-mutex-broker:latest"
```

what's the proper way to do this? My guess is:

```
docker tag "oresoftware/live-mutex-broker:latest" "oresoftware/live-mutex-broker:1.0.2"
```

but I don't really know. Nope didn't work, I tried that, and I get:

> Error response from daemon: No such image:
>   oresoftware/live-mutex-broker:latest

so maybe switch the operands?

Answer (score 2):

Use the following command to tag the currently created image for online repository

```
 $ docker tag oresoftware/live-mutex-broker:1.0.2 oresoftware/live-mutex-broker:latest
```

Then upload the image to docker hub with the command

```
$ docker push "oresoftware/live-mutex-broker:latest"
```

**Explaination**

To tag a docker image you use this pattern:

```
docker tag <container-image-name> <username>/<repo>:<tag>
```

And then just remove the `<container-image-name>` from the above command and replace tag key-word with push to push it to the repository.

```
docker push <username>/<repo>:<tag>
```